# how to prevent user edit attribute called price value of this input, exemple : price="100" , how to disable changing it's value?

Tags: javascript, html

how to prevent user edit attribute called price  value of this input, exemple : price="100"  ,  how to disable changing it's value ?

```
<div class="form-check form-check-custom form-check-custom-service">
    <input class="form-check-input radio-button radio-button-services-0" type="radio" value="Yes" price="100">
        <label class="form-check-label radio-label" for="rdbServiceArrYes_0_5_1">                                             Yes 
            <span class="price-label">100  USD                                             </span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Change it how?? How is the user altering it?

Comment: using inspect element

Comment: Nope, nothing you can do

Comment: The user can change *anything* you send to their browser. html, javascript, etc. The only way to prevent that is by keeping it on the server.

Comment: can i encrypt it ?  and decrypted it when i send it server side using ajax  ?

Comment: No, you can not. If it is rendered, the user can change it. That is why we have backend code with validation.

Comment: Why do you need the browser to inform you about your own prices? Aren't prices something you set server-side?

Comment: thank you all @ÁlvaroGonzález yes should be server side thank you

Comment: Then it's a non-problem, isn't it? It doesn't really matter if user fiddles with HTML, you'll apply the right prices anyway.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález yes no problem , thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable it. Anyone with inspect element can change it locally.